# simple javascript if not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I'm new to javascript and am having issues with a seemingly simple if/else statement.

Can anyone let me know why the below isn't working please (Im pulling my hair out)

```
var is_expanded = false;
if (is_expanded==false) {
    alert('no');
    is_expanded = true;
} else {
    alert('yes');
}
```

I always get the 'no' alert (I never get to the else part).

Cheers for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You previous line of code says `var is_expanded = false;` 
which means `if (is_expanded==false)` will always evaluate to `true`.

So that is exactly what you are getting as output. What did you expect?

Next time when your same method is called, the value for `is_expanded` is again reset to `false` due to your first line of code. Then again it will alert `no`

Answer (score 9):

This is working as designed.

The condition is checked when you say `if`. It then goes into the correct block, in this case the one that alerts "no".

The condition does not get re-evaluated after the block has been executed. That's just not how the `if` statement works, not in any language I know.

Depending on what you want to do, there are other patterns and constructs that can help you, for example a [`while`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while) loop. Maybe show the real use case that you need this for.

Answer (score 2):

That's because `is_expanded` always equals `false` because you've set it as `false` BEFORE the if statement.

else will not fire unless `is_expanded` equals `true` before the if statement.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal. You have set the variable `is_expanded` to `false` so in the if statement you are always entering the `alert('no');` part. After you set the variable to true but there is no longer any if statement executed.

Answer (score 1):

```
var is_expanded = false;
if (is_expanded==false) {
    alert('no');
    is_expanded = true;
} else {
    alert('yes');
}
```

Congratulations! Your code is working perfectly, so stop pulling your hair out.

The nature of IF/ELSE is that only *one* of them fires per pass. So, your code checks whether `is_expanded` is FALSE. If it's false, it will run the IF part. If not, it'll run the ELSE part.

Just read it like english.

`If something, do this. Otherwise, do something else`

Even if you change the value of the variable inside one of the blocks, it won't matter because once it checks the block, it moves on.